# Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: java, xml, maven, tomcat

I need to deploy a server tomcat with maven, but I have an error due to connection.. I don't understand

tomcat-user.xml

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"                                                       
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                      
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"                         
          version="1.0">                                                                             

<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-script"/>
```

maven/settings.xml

```
<server>
  <id>TomcatServer</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>password</password>
</server>
```

And pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    war
    com.epitech.area
    Area
    1.0-SNAPSHOT

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>web\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path></path>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>password</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
        <artifactId>scribejava-apis</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>[4.0,)</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

mvn error

mvn tomcat:deploy

```
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) @ Area ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/Area  
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.630 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-24T18:07:13+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/60M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-
plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project Area: Cannot invoke Tomcat 
manager: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]
```

I don't undrstand why, Can you help me, Maven is very blurring for me.

My port is not used, and when I run it with artifact in IntelliJ my app is launched.

I need a .war with Maven

Comment: I assume you can connect tomcat start page via browser? And maybe able to open login form for manager pages by pressing manager link? If it is only war you need mvn:package should be enough. And deploy also generates it to target directory even deploy fails.

Comment: When I run war, I have a blank page to localhost:8080. with 'mvn tomcat:run-war'

Comment: So you do not have tomcat separately installed but rely on `tomcat7-maven-plugin`? And maybe some IDE tomcat server installation?

Comment: I installed tomcat separattly, I just use the maven plugin to use Tomcat, I don't installed tomcat up to an IDE

Comment: First you should have access to manager with browser, without any maven:run-war or deploy to see it working ok. Maybe you want to add also `manager-gui` role to admin.